# setting number of records per page using Active Reports 9

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, activereports

I am working on Page Reports type of Active Reports 9 and I want to set the number of records/ rows displayed per page. By default it is showing 2 records per page, spanning up to 11 pages. I would want to display  10 records per page. Can this be done using any of the existing properties of the reports or do I have to add a script to execute the same? Since I'm new to active Reports would be great if I get an aid on the scripting if necessary.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveReports FPL(Fixed Page Layout) reports are designed for exactly this type of situation.  They allow the report developer to build reports that look exactly the same at runtime as they do at design time.

FixedSize is a property available on the data region(table, matrix, list, etc.) controls of a page report.  By setting the fixed size property to a certain height, you can add or reduce the number of records that will be displayed on a single page.  More information on setting the FixedSize of a data region can be found here: http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/SetFixedSizeOfADataRegion.html

If you're still having trouble, a sample demonstrating the displaying of 10 records on a page can be found here: 
http://publicfiles.componentone.com/Patrick/10RecordsPerPage.zip